# Telephoto auto focus on D3100 not working

Tags: troubleshooting, telephoto, nikon-d3100

I can seem to get the 200mm telephoto to manual focus on anything...and it doesnt work with auto focus either. Is someone able to offer help or suggestions as to whats happening.

Thanks...Marnie

Comment: You can't manual focus...as in, the camera isn't recognizing something that IS in focus or turning the focus ring doesn't do anything? Does the camera recognize focus but the viewfinder appears blurred still?

Comment: Has it stopped working or has it never worked for you? Also, which 200mm? Nikon has made a few, and probably third parties have too.

Answer (score 0):

The Nikon D3100 (like many of their other entry level models) does not have an internal focusing motor. You'll need to use an newer AF-S lens with its own focusing motor in order to use autofocus with this body. Most features on other recent lenses should work just fine, for details see the lens section of the [tech specs](https://www.nikonusa.com/en/nikon-products/product-archive/dslr-cameras/d3100.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs).